# How can I convert UTF-16 to UTF-32 in java?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-16, utf-32

I have looked for solutions, but there doesn't seem to be much on this topic. I have found solutions that suggest:

```
String unicodeString = new String("utf8 here");
byte[] bytes = String.getBytes("UTF8"); 
String converted = new String(bytes,"UTF16");
```

for converting to utf16 from utf8, however, java doesn't handle "UTF32", which makes this solution unviable. Does anyone know any other way on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after searching I got this to work:

```
    public static String convert16to32(String toConvert){
        for (int i = 0; i < toConvert.length(); ) {
            int codePoint = Character.codePointAt(toConvert, i);
            i += Character.charCount(codePoint);
            //System.out.printf("%x%n", codePoint);
            String utf32 = String.format("0x%x%n", codePoint);
            return utf32;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Glad you found a working solution! Sorry for not keeping my promise :P I worked on my code but ran into strange issues that I could not reproduce on other systems. My idea involved using `codePointAt()` as well and it was generally quite similar (just in case you were curious).

Comment: `String utf32` should be declared above the loop, and `return utf32;` should be after the loop, Otherwise, there is no point in having the loop at all.

Answer (score 4):

Java does handle UTF-32, try this test

```
    byte[] a = "1".getBytes("UTF-32");
    System.out.println(a.length);
```

it will show that arrays' lentgh = 4

Comment: Then how would I do the conversion since it isn't working for me?

Comment: @DanielMedina [According to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), UTF-32 isn't guaranteed to be present on all systems; it isn't even mentioned on the page. Hold on, I'm working on an answer for you.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the effort

Answer (score 1):

```
public static char[] bytesToHex(byte[] raw) {
    int length = raw.length;
    char[] hex = new char[length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int value = (raw[i] + 256) % 256;
        int highIndex = value >> 4;
        int lowIndex = value & 0x0f;
        hex[i * 2 + 0] = kDigits[highIndex];
        hex[i * 2 + 1] = kDigits[lowIndex];
    }
    return hex;
}



byte[] bytearr = converted.getBytes("UTF-32");
System.out.println("With UTF-32 encoding:\t" + String.valueOf(bytesToHex(bytearr)));
System.out.println("With UTF-32 decoding:\t" + new String((bytearr), "UTF-32"));
```