# Java: Write to a file in UTF-32 Format

Tags: java, unicode, randomaccessfile

Is it possible to write Strings to a file in utf-32 format? For example: the RandomAccessFile class only offers the writeUTF() Method, which writes the String in a modifed UTF-8 format.

Lets say my task is to write every existing unicode character into a file :).

Comment: I think you can use this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java

Comment: UTF-32LE or UTF-32BE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert your string to bytes in the UTF-32 format, and then write write those bytes to your random file

```
RandomAccessFile file = ...
String str = "Hi";
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-32");
file.write(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could Use `BufferedWriter`:

```
public class SampleCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String aString = "File contents";
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("outfilename"), "UTF-32"));
        try {
            out.write(aString);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Or you could use

> Analogously, the class java.io.OutputStreamWriter acts as a bridge between characters streams and bytes streams. Create a Writer with this class to be able to write bytes to the file:

```
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outfile), "UTF-32");
```

Or you can also use String format like below:

```
public static String convertTo32(String toConvert){
    for (int i = 0; i < toConvert.length(); ) {
        int codePoint = Character.codePointAt(toConvert, i);
        i += Character.charCount(codePoint);
        //System.out.printf("%x%n", codePoint);
        String utf32 = String.format("0x%x%n", codePoint);
        return utf32;
    }
    return null;
}
```

See [How can I convert UTF-16 to UTF-32 in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393811/).

Comment: While your first solution is good, the `convertTo32` is flawed, a string in java always has the UTF16 encoding internally, and cannot represent something else

Comment: Also, `String utf32` should be declared above the loop, and `return utf32;` should be after the loop, Otherwise, there is no point in having the loop at all.

Comment: When you directly use [someone-else's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36394647/1542723), make sure to properly attribute them, else it's called plagiarism.