# Xml Reader parsing character outside BMP to surrogate pairs which results in invalid xml

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser, xerces

I am trying to parse an xml which contains hex value of `&#x1d4c5;`. This represents the mathematical symbol . The output that I am getting is `&#55349;&#56517;`.

What am I doing wrong?

example input xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <data>&#x1d4c5;</data>
</root>
```

output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <data>&#55349;&#56517;</data>
</root>
```

Code to obtain XML reader :

```
factory = org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newInstance();
final XMLReader xmlReader;
        xmlReader = factory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
```

I am using UTF-8 encoding to decode while parsing.

The code I am using to read and write xml is this method :

```
public void readAndWriteXml(InputSource inputSource, OutputStream out) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {

            XMLReader xmlReader = getXmlReader();
            Serializer serializer = SerializerFactory.getSerializer(configProps);
            serializer.setOutputStream(out);
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(serializer.asContentHandler());

            if(logger != null){
                getLogger().debug("starting xml parsing" + LocalTime.now());
            }
            xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
            if(logger != null){
                getLogger().debug("end xml parsing" + LocalTime.now());
            }

        }
```

getXMLReader() is this :

```
final XMLReader xmlReader;
        xmlReader = factory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        xmlReader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes", true);
        xmlReader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features" +
                "/namespaces", true);
        xmlReader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", true);
//        xmlReader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
        xmlReader.setEntityResolver(wrappedEntityResolver);
        xmlReader.setErrorHandler(new SaxErrorHandler());
        return xmlReader;
```

Here I am initialising the class :

```
public XmlNormalizer(String catalogPath) throws IOException {
        // We want the Apache XML parser, not the embedded Oracle Java version.
        factory = org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        List<Path> catalogFiles = this.findByFileName(new File(catalogPath).toPath(), CATALOG_FILENAME_PATTERN);
        String[] catalogArray = catalogFiles.stream().map(Path::toString).toArray(String[]::new);
        configProps = OutputPropertiesFactory.getDefaultMethodProperties("xml");
        XMLCatalogResolver xmlCatalogResolver = new XMLCatalogResolver(catalogArray, true);
        wrappedEntityResolver = new WrappedEntityResolver(xmlCatalogResolver);
    }
```

WrappedEntityResolver is just a wrapper around `import org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver;`

Comment: Java's `char`s are 16 bits long. Characters with Unicode code higher than 65535 must be represented by two Java `char`s.

Comment: Is there a way to get the mathematical symbol in the output in java? @MauricePerry

Comment: Have a look at that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36394647/7036419

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code to demonstrate how the content is read and written?

Comment: What is in `configProps`?  What is `wrappedEntityResolver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output is most definitely wrong, but it's hard to tell why.

What are the properties passed to the serializer?

If you serialize with Saxon, then with default encoding (UTF-8) the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
   <data></data>
</root>
```

while with encoding=us-ascii the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <data>&#x1d4c5;</data>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael, it worked with saxon. Is there a way to pass some properties to the serializer I am using above. I wonder why it resolves it like that

Comment: `configProps` contains the relevant properties and it would be useful to know what values you are setting, but this doesn't explain the bug.